# How to keep matched source labels in Prometheus relabel config

Tags: prometheus

Pod in Kubernetes exports metrics at some port, and this port is specified in annotation. Is there any method to only keep container port that matches port in annotation?

I tried something like this, but it is not working

```
relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation__prometheus_io_port,__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number]
     regex: (.+);$1
     action: keep
```

I expect that Prometheus will scrape metrics from exposed port if

```
__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation__prometheus_io_port == __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number
```

The question is about regex. How to match first group "(+.)" that is port in annotation with container port?